# Appropriate Structure for Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll call

Tags: .net, task-parallel-library, asp.net-web-api

I want to make sure that I am using ContinueWhenAll appropriately.  I have a number of calls which will run asynch and then I want to complete to a final task only after the other tasks have completed successfully and after I do some calcs on the results to see if I should instead stop processing and return a forbidden HTTP result.  What I am unsure about is whether the final line will actually wait for all the other tasks to complete, or whether I need to structure it differently.  If so, how should the last line be structured so that it is called ONLY if I get past the evaluation of if(getPlatformTask.Result...

```
// run some tasks and then gather them here
Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(new Task[]{ getPlatformTask, getUserTask },
    (tasks) =>
    {
        Task.WaitAll(tasks);

        if (getPlatformTask.Result == null || getUserTask.Result == null)
        {
           return Task<HttpResponseMessage>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
           {
              return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
           });
        }
    });

// will this line below get called before the inner task above completes?   
return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
```

Comment: Do you use `result` anywhere? Why are you starting a `Task` just to return something? Your code is very confusing to me.

Comment: I removed result.  Its confusing because I still don't understand how to properly use Tasks ;).  Someone suggested that all I really need is a Task.WaitAll() since I am not returning anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to block the current thread until all the tasks complete, you can simply use `Task.WaitAll()`, no need to use continuation tasks. But keep in mind that blocked thread is a thread that does nothing but use up resources (like memory). Blocking a thread is often easier, but less efficient way to do things.

The code might look like this:

```
// run the tasks

Task.WaitAll(getPlatformTask, getUserTask);

// process the results

return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
```

And no, in your version, the last line can (and most likely will) execute before all the tasks are complete. `ContinueWhenAll()` does not block, that's the whole point of it.

**EDIT:** I just realized that your method returns a `Task`. So you actually don't have to block the thread, you can instead return a `Task` that is completed when all the work is done. It could look like this:

```
// run the tasks

var result = Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAll(
    new[] { getPlatformTask, getUserTask },
    _ =>
    {
        // process the results

        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    });

return result.Unwrap();
```

Here, `result` is `Task<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>`, but you need just `Task<HttpResponseMessage>`. To do that, you can use [the `Unwrap()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd781129.aspx).

Comment: Ah, so you're saying I don't even need that continuation task at all.  I can simply do a Task.WaitAll() and it will wait until ALL the threads I have spawned are completed.  I know it will block which is what I want as all the tasks have to complete and they have to evaluate correctly before I allow it to get to the final line (or I short circuit the response with a HTTP forbidden.  Let me know if this assumption is correct.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm saying.